# Regexp- regular expression to match a string which contains block from a variable

Tags: regex

I was trying to figure out regular expression of to search/match block statement from a value which is store in a variable.

Below contents I have stored in a variable and I am looking a regular expression in python to grep

```
authentication {
admin-enabled enabled
syslog-admin-state disabled
}
```

from this input:

```
current-secret
key-min-len 8
search-method priority
global-servers on
privilege-level-admin 2
privilege-level-super 10
privilege-level-diag 15
authentication {
admin-enabled enabled
syslog-admin-state disabled
}
authorization {
admin-enabled disabled
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of extracting the required config block

`authentication\s*{(\n|.)*?}`

**Human readable format:** Match the characters in `authentication` sequentially, then any number of white spaces `\s*`. Then match a `{` followed by any number of new line or non new line chars `(\n|.)*` . Lazy match with `?` and at the end match `}`

See it at work: https://regexr.com/3h209

Comment: authentication { 
admin-enabled enabled 
syslog-admin-state disabled 
server  1.2.3.4 {
          address 1.2.3.4
          priority 1
          port 49
          admin-enabled enabled
        }
        server  2.3.4.5 {
          address 2.3.4.5
          priority 2
          port 2
          admin-enabled enabled
        }

} As per above statement ,I am looking a regular expression to grep entire data between authentication { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
authentication\s*{[^}]*}
```

See [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kn4gqi/1)

Comment: Why the outer brackets?

Comment: What about them ? Isn't OP trying to capture them as well ?

Comment: The entire match is captured as group zero. You don't need the brackets.

Comment: Oh yeah the parentheses,  thought you meant the braces brackets. Yeah you're right, it's useless, removing them.

Comment: If contents is stored in a file then expression you suggested will work.

Comment: What do you mean ? That it wouldn't work with a variable ?